# how to take binary string input from user in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I want to take input from user in binary, What I want is something like:
10101
11110

Then I need to perform bitwise OR on this. I know how to take input and how to perform bitwise OR, only I want to know is how to convert because what I am currently using is not giving right result. What I tried is as below:

```
let aBits: Int16 = Int16(a)! //a is String "10101"
let bBits: Int16 = Int16(b)! //b is String "11110"
let combinedbits = aBits | bBits
```

Edit: I don't need decimal to binary conversion with radix, as my string already have only 0 and 1
String can have upto 500 characters like:
10011011111010110111001011001001101110111110110001001111001111101111010110110111‌​00111001100011111010
this is beyond Int limit, how to handle that in Swift?

Edit2 : As per vacawama 's answer, below code works great:

```
let maxAB = max(a.count, b.count)
let paddedA = String(repeating: "0", count: maxAB - a.count) + a
let paddedB = String(repeating: "0", count: maxAB - b.count) + b

let Str = String(zip(paddedA, paddedB).map({ $0 == ("0", "0") ? "0" : "1" }))
```

I can have array of upto 500 string and each string can have upto 500 characters. Then I have to get all possible pair and perform bitwise OR and  count maximum number of 1's. Any idea to make above solution more efficient? Thank you

Comment: you want to convert string to binary ?

Comment: yes, while that string is already having only 0 and 1, not alphabets or numbers in decimal

Comment: Is this some kind of school exercise?

Comment: @Bhanupriya FYI, if your `String` contains `10101` this is still a `String` only you know this is binary string but system will ready it as `String` only.

Comment: Yes, I know that 10101 is still a String, Thats what I asked, how to convert it to binary

Comment: This comes from the basic misunderstanding of the difference between a number and a string representation of number.

Comment: Then you will have to write the algorithm yourself.

Comment: `50` binary digits is less than 7 bytes and that is fine for `Int64`.

Comment: @Sulthan, OP said *up to 500 characters*.

Comment: @vacawama missed that number :)

Comment: @vacawama 's answer is good but I can have array of up to 500 string, each with up to 500 character, then I will compare all of them, it would be too heavy, is there any efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Since you need arbitrarily long binary numbers, do everything with strings.

This function first pads the two inputs to the same length, and then uses `zip` to pair the digits and `map` to compute the `OR` for each pair of characters.  The resulting array of characters is converted back into a `String` with `String()`.

```
func binaryOR(_ a: String, _ b: String) -> String {
    let maxAB = max(a.count, b.count)
    let paddedA = String(repeating: "0", count: maxAB - a.count) + a
    let paddedB = String(repeating: "0", count: maxAB - b.count) + b

    return String(zip(paddedA, paddedB).map({ $0 == ("0", "0") ? "0" : "1" }))
}

print(binaryOR("11", "1100"))    // "1111"
print(binaryOR("1000", "0001"))  // "1001"
```

---

> I can have array of upto 500 string and each string can have upto 500
>   characters. Then I have to get all possible pair and perform bitwise
>   OR and count maximum number of 1's. Any idea to make above solution
>   more efficient?

You will have to do `500 * 499 / 2` (which is `124,750` comparisons).  It is important to avoid unnecessary and/or repeated work.

I would recommend:

1. Do an initial pass to loop though your strings to find out the length of the largest one.  Then pad all of your strings to this length.  I would keep track of the original length of each string in a tiny stuct:

   ```
   struct BinaryNumber {
       var string: String  // padded string
       var length: Int     // original length before padding
   }
   ```
2. Modify the `binaryOR` function to take `BinaryNumbers` and return `Int`, the count of "1"s in the OR.

   ```
   func binaryORcountOnes(_ a: BinaryNumber, _ b: BinaryNumber) -> Int { 
       let maxAB = max(a.length, b.length)           
       return zip(a.string.suffix(maxAB), b.string.suffix(maxAB)).reduce(0) { total, pair in return total + (pair == ("0", "0") ? 0 : 1) }
   }
   ```

   Note:  The use of `suffix` helps the efficiency by only checking the digits that matter.  If the original strings had length `2` and `3`, then only the last `3` digits will be OR-ed even if they're padded to length `500`.
3. Loop and compare all pairs of `BinaryNumber`s to find largest count of ones:

   ```
   var numbers: [BinaryNumber]  // This array was created in step 1

   maxOnes = 0
   for i in 0 ..< (numbers.count - 1) {
       for j in (i + 1) ..< numbers.count {
           let ones = binaryORcountOnes(numbers[i], numbers[j])
           if ones > maxOnes {
               maxOnes = ones
           }
       }
   }

   print("maxOnes = \(maxOnes)")
   ```

---

**Additional idea for speedup**

OR can't create more ones than were in the original two numbers, and the number of ones can't exceed the maximum length of either of the original two numbers.  So, if you count the ones in each number when you are padding them and store that in your `struct` in a `var ones: Int` property, you can use that to see if you should even bother calling `binaryORcountOnes`:

```
maxOnes = 0
for i in 0 ..< (numbers.count - 1) {
    for j in (i + 1) ..< numbers.count {
        if maxOnes < min(numbers[i].ones + numbers[j].ones, numbers[i].length, numbers[j].length) {
            let ones = binaryORcountOnes(numbers[i], numbers[j])
            if ones > maxOnes {
                maxOnes = ones
            }
        }
    }
}
```

By the way, the `length` of the original string should really just be the minimum length that includes the highest order `1`.  So if the original string was `"00101"`, then the `length` should be `3` because that is all you need to store `"101"`.

Comment: Best answer..!!

Comment: Thank you @vacawama but I can have array of 500 string, each with 500 characters, it won't be efficient for that. Is there any more efficient way to do this ?

Comment: @Bhanupriya, this is what we call *shifting requirements*.  Why don't you update your question to tell us everything you're trying to do instead of incrementally adding requirements.  Perhaps this function isn't too slow, but you're calling it too many times. What exactly are your requirements, and how are you using a function like this one to satisfy them?

Answer (score 0):

```
let number = Int(a, radix: 2)
```

Radix helps using binary instead of decimical value

Comment: Hi @Vyacheslav, I have already tried it, this works for converting decimal to binary but as I already mentioned my input is not in decimal, it only have 0 and 1 but it is string, how to convert it to binary

Comment: No, like Int("10101", radix: 2) gives 21 while I want String "10101" to binary

Comment: That's correct. 21 is a number you are looking for. Where so you want to show it like 10101 instead of 21?

Comment: Yes I want like 10101 only, and then perform bitwise OR with another 11110

Comment: Where do you want to show? This is only representation mode.you can use bite operations regardless radix. 21 is the same as 10101

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169647/discussion-between-bhanupriya-and-vyacheslav).

Answer (score 0):

You can use radix for converting your string. Once converted, you can do a bitwise OR and then check the nonzeroBitCount to count the number of 1's

```
let a = Int("10101", radix: 2)!
let b = Int("11110", radix: 2)!

let bitwiseOR = a | b
let nonZero = bitwiseOR.nonzeroBitCount
```

Answer (score 0):

As I already commented above "10101" is actually a `String` not a `Binary` so `"10101" | "11110"` will not calculate what you actually needed.

So what you need to do is convert both value in `decimal` then use `bitwiseOR` and convert the result back to in `Binary String` `(in which format you have the data "11111" not 11111)`

```
let a1 = Int("10101", radix: 2)!
let b1 = Int("11110", radix: 2)!
var result = 21 | 30
print(result)
```

> **Output:** 31

Now convert it back to `binary string`

```
let binaryString = String(result, radix: 2)
print(binaryString)
```

> **Output:** 11111

**--: EDIT :--**

I'm going to answer a basic example of how to calculate `bitwiseOR` as the question is specific for not use inbuilt function as string is very large to be converted into an `Int`.

> **Algorithm:** 1|0 = 1,  1|1 = 1, 0|0 = 0, 0|1 = 1

So, What we do is to fetch all the characters from `String` one by one the will perform the `|` operation and append it to another `String`.

```
var str1 = "100101" // 37
var str2 = "10111" // 23
/// Result should be "110111" -> "55"

// #1. Make both string equal
let length1 = str1.characters.count
let length2 = str2.characters.count
if length1 != length2 {
    let maxLength = max(length1, length2)
    for index in 0..<maxLength {
        if str1.characters.count < maxLength {
            str1 = "0" + str1
        }
        if str2.characters.count < maxLength {
            str2 = "0" + str2
        }
    }
}

// #2. Get the index and compare one by one in bitwise OR
// a) 1 - 0 = 1,
// b) 0 - 1 = 1,
// c) 1 - 1 = 1,
// d) 0 - 0 = 0
let length = max(str1.characters.count, str2.characters.count)
var newStr = ""
for index in 0..<length {
    let charOf1 = Int(String(str1[str1.index(str1.startIndex, offsetBy: index)]))!
    let charOf2 = Int(String(str2[str2.index(str2.startIndex, offsetBy: index)]))!
    let orResult = charOf1 | charOf2
    newStr.append("\(orResult)")
}

print(newStr)
```

> **Output:** 110111 // 55

I would like to refer [Understanding Bitwise Operators](https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/understanding-bitwise-operators--active-11301) for more detail.

Comment: Oh god, you could get the same result by padding the shorter and then use `zip(a, b).map { $0.0 == 1 || $0.1 == 1 ? "1" : "0" }`

Comment: @Sulthan Oh thanks:)... But `zip("100101", "10111").map { $0.0 == "1" || $0.1 == "1" ? "1" : "0" }` is printing `["1", "0", "1", "1", "1"]`.

Comment: Thats great.. this is so cool just a single line. Is there any way to append the `0` as prefix to make the string equal?

Comment: There is already an answer doing that https://stackoverflow.com/a/50000084/669586

Comment: @Sulthan Might be it helps the OP to understand in deep as the `Swift` functions quite fast forward and not too much familiar with new users. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
func addBinary(_ a: String, _ b: String) {


var result = ""
let arrA = Array(a)
let arrB = Array(b)

var lengthA = arrA.count - 1
var lengthB = arrB.count - 1
var sum = 0

while lengthA >= 0 || lengthB >= 0 || sum == 1 {

    sum += (lengthA >= 0) ? Int(String(arrA[lengthA]))! : 0

    sum += (lengthB >= 0) ? Int(String(arrB[lengthB]))! : 0

    result = String((sum % 2)) + result

    sum /=  2
    lengthA -= 1
    lengthB -= 1
}

print(result) }
```

addBinary("11", "1")

Comment: binary add for two strings: 
a: "11"
b: "1"
result: 100